# Timelion Error Message: [timelion_vis] > Error: in cell #1: [search_phase_execution_exception]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

When trying to create visualizations with Timelion, I keep getting this error message: [timelion_vis] > Error: in cell #1: [search_phase_execution_exception]

It is the full message, there is no more information provided.

I recently did a project about Access Log Analytics using the ELK-Stack. I set up Logstash and fed our Apache Access Logs to Elasticsearch and in Kibana I created a handful of visualizations. Timelion was especially helpful, I have a bunch of queries that work perfectly - in Kibana 5.2, the version I was required to use for the project.

Now we have it all set up on a live server using the current versions (7.3) of Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana. I made adjustments to my visualizations to accomodate the current versions, however I have problems setting up Timelion.

We can't find any more help in the logs either, there is just nothing there. No hint as to what might be wrong.?

Even with .es(*) I get the error. Using my old queries I get the same error, I checked my syntax, it is fine.

However if I type .es(index=logstash-*, timefield='@timestamp', metric='avg:size') I get a result.

The size-field holds a numeric value. all my other queries refer to fields with string-values. So there seems to be problem with that, I just cannot get behind it.

Any ideas? Has anyone else encountered this error before?

This is what comes up in the Kibana Logs:

```
Error:  in cell #1: [search_phase_execution_exception] : Error:  in cell #1: [search_phase_execution_exception] 
    at throwWithCell (/usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/core_plugins/timelion/server/handlers/chain_runner.js:54:11)
    at /usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/core_plugins/timelion/server/handlers/chain_runner.js:205:13
    at arrayEach (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/lodash/index.js:1315:13)
    at Function. (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3393:13)
    at /usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/core_plugins/timelion/server/handlers/chain_runner.js:197:23
    at tryCatcher (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:643:18)
    at SettledPromiseArray.PromiseArray._resolve (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:126:19)
    at SettledPromiseArray._promiseResolved (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/settle.js:16:14)
    at SettledPromiseArray._promiseRejected (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/settle.js:32:17)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:581:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
```

Comment: Can you also check in the ES server logs (not the Kibana one)? the error must show up there too

Comment: Checked the ES server logs, but they give no more information on what might be wrong. Just repeat the error message, sadly